# creating repositories in openrdf sesame other than openrdf-workbench UI

Tags: sesame, rdfstore

I am using openrdf-sesame standalone server as my datastore.

In development, I use openrdf-workbench UI to create my repositories.

What is the correct way to create repositories in prodcution?

Is there a openrdf-workbench api? If so please point me to it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [RemoteRepositoryManager](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/manager/RemoteRepositoryManager.html) object for your server. Once you have this, you can use it to retrieve/remove existing repositories as well as create new repositories.

This is a bit underdocumented in the Sesame documentation. However, see [this weblog article](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/the-repositorymanager/) for explanation and code examples.